# Always use root as base url with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I use a mix between Laravel and Vue-Router, so I have my main app that uses `someurl.com/` as my base however when I use a standard Laravel navigation over to `someurl.com/settings` I can't then use my navigation bar to jump to routes as when I click on a route it becomes `someurl.com/settings/dashboard` instead of `someurl.com/dashboard`.

How do I always ensure that VueRouter uses the absolute root of the URL, I can simply just set it to hide the navigation and navigate back to root just using a standard `<a>` tag but I'm trying to avoid that.

Any ideas?

**My router is below:**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    base: '/',
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});
```

Comment: What does the link in you navigation bar look like? Is it a `router-link` component or a normal html `a` component?

Comment: @DelenaMalan It's a `router-link`.

Comment: What's the value of the `to` prop in your router-link? And how did you define your `/dashboard` route?

Comment: The value is `to="/"`. I don't think that's my issue, I want to get be able to click on the router link and return to the base url if I'm at `/settings` as shown in my question.

Comment: Your question says "when I click on a route it becomes `someurl.com/settings/dashboard` instead of `someurl.com/dashboard`".

Comment: Yes, so if I navigate to `someurl.com/settings` as a standard link, using php. I still have my vue navigation bar which uses vue-router. So when I click on a navigation item in that bar, how can I get it to use the root URL so it does not become `someurl.com/settings/vue-route` and instead becomes `someurl.com/vue-route`.

Comment: It should do that by default if you define your routes correctly.

Comment: Let me make it clear that `/settings` is a PHP route, not a Vue route. I'm quite an avid user of Vue and don't believe it to be a mistake on my behalf. Vue-Router uses the page that you are currently on. If I turn off history mode it becomes `someurl.com/settings/#/vue-route` when I'd like to to become `someurl.com/#/vue-route`.